# How do I perfectly fit things in the bottom banner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem where I have a lot of items I want to fit in my website's bottom banner, but when I try adding them they get messed up because of how I spaced them, now I really just want to know how I can fix this and what a good way could be for not doing this in any of my future projects. Here is an example of what I want:

[image: Example]

I want to make the text in the center go left towards the icons and I want the pictures at the bottom left to go to the center-right. I tried messing with this before but the banner always became smaller or the images would get messed up and other things like that. Here is the code of my website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>FAQ</title>

        <!-- Novo Sans Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+TC:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Crimson Text Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Architect's Daughter Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>

h1 {

    text-align: center;

}

.arrow {

    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;

}

.indicator {
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: left;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: 0.2s ease transform;
}

.collapsible {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid thin;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}


.collapsible.active .indicator {

    transform: rotate(45deg);

}


.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#div2 {

    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 290px;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(173, 12, 7);
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;

}

.contactInfo {

    text-align: center;
    color: white;

}

#cInfo {

    padding-right: 1px;

}

#phoneInfo {

    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-right: 300px;

}

#phoneIcon {

    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 100px;

}

#emailInfo {

    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-right: 200px;

}

#emailIcon {

    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 100px;

}

#farmer {

float: left;

}

#littleShop {

    
    float: left;


}

</style>

<body>

<div class="logo"><img src="CSS/logo.jpg" id="logo" width="250" height="150"><a href="#"></a></div>

<nav>

<div style="width: 750px; margin: 0 auto;">

<div id="navbar">
    
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

</div>

</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/faq.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/new_main_css.css">

<h1>FAQ</h1>

<button class="collapsible" data-toggle=""><b>Questions and Answers</b><i class="arrow indicator"></i></button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>


<div id="div2">
    
<h1 class="contactInfo" id="cInfo">Contact information</h1>

    <img src="CSS/phoneIconNew.png" width="40" height="40" id="phoneIcon">
    <h2 class="contactInfo" id="phoneInfo">Business Contact: 072 000 000 0000</h2>
    <img src="CSS/emailIconNew.png" width="40" height="40" id="emailIcon">
    <h2 class="contactInfo" id="emailInfo">Busienss Email: exampleemail@example.com</h2>

    <img src="CSS/littleshopnew.jpg" id="littleShop">
    <img src="CSS/farmer.png" id="farmer">

</div>


</body>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</html>
```

JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/5309uzrd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed `div2` from `block` to `flex`

Css

```
#div2 {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 290px;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(173, 12, 7);
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

}
#div2 .container{
    width: 50%;
}
.contactInfo {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Html

```
<div id="div2">
 <h1 class="contactInfo" id="cInfo">Contact information</h1>
  <div class="container">
        <img src="CSS/phoneIconNew.png" width="40" height="40" id="phoneIcon">
        <h2 class="contactInfo" id="phoneInfo">Business Contact: 072 000 000 0000</h2>
        <img src="CSS/emailIconNew.png" width="40" height="40" id="emailIcon">
        <h2 class="contactInfo" id="emailInfo">Busienss Email: exampleemail@example.com</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <img src="CSS/littleshopnew.jpg" id="littleShop">
      <img src="CSS/farmer.png" id="farmer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But might I ask what exactly the flex does?

Comment: Sure, you can get a better idea [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)